# App engine for high memory rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Looks like the most powerful instance type you can have in Google App Engine is one with 2G memory. One of our Rails application reaches the memory limit quickly on higher load. Autoscaling helps but wondering if there is a way to add more power instances in GAE?

If not, how have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

yes, in [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) the higher tier is `F4_HIGHMEM`    with `2048 MB` of memory. You have 3 ways to [scale up with standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed):

**Automatic**: based on request rate, response latencies, and other application metrics.

**Basic**: creates dynamic instances when your application receives requests.

**Manual**: uses resident instances that continuously run the specified number of instances regardless of the load level.

Therefore, the question here would be how are you reaching this limit? How are you managing your memory? Take a look into your console metrics: memoryusage. A ladder graphs shown a bad usage of the memory. When deploying apps in the Cloud, you must have in mind that the usage of the resources bust be more accurate.

You can analyze and check if choosing an automatic scale based on `Max concurrent Requests` would be a good option for you to mitigate your issue with the memory.

This is for Standard, [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) is managed different. You can specify from 0.9 to 6.5 GB per CPU core.

Comment: Yes, we have thought about Flexible instances but those are more expensive. We will try to play with different values for concurrent number of requests to work around memory limitation. Thanks.